# How often should "self clean" and "allergen clean" functions be used in an air conditioner?

Tags: air-conditioning, air-quality

Some air conditioners, for example Mitsubishi heavy industries SRK20ZJ-S have "self clean" and "allergen clean" functions. First takes 2 hours to complete, latter 1.5 hours.

How often should they be used? I understand this depends, but roughly - once per day/week/month?

Comment: Does the manual say anything about how often?

Comment: @Steven - The [manual](http://www.mhiaa.com.au/images/usermanuals/RAC/RLA012A013_SRK_ZJ.pdf) doesn't say anything about periodic use of the allergen clear and about the self-clean says "CLEAN operation should be run after AUTO, COOL and DRY operation to remove the moisture from inside the indoor unit and control the growth of mold and bacteria".

Comment: Yes, the manual says nothing. Self clean is rather long operation, so I'm not sure if it should be performed after each COOL, DRY cycle.

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of any manufacture recommendations, I would suggest that you use the self-clean method whenever you notice a smell coming from the unit.  As a related tip, if you ever notice the A/C in your car smelling bad, run it on max cool and max fan for 20minutes as this kills most of the mold and bacteria that is causing the smell; my guess is that this 2hour cycle does something similar.

I'm really not sure what the allergen clean might do but maybe run if a couple times a year.

It's probably worth noting that most A/C units don't have these functions and work fine for many years; it might be more of a marketing gimmick than anything else.

Comment: Hi Steven. Here I was talking about home A/C but not car A/C. Manual says that "allergen clean" is special set of cool/heat/dry operations, 1.5 hours long. But it says nothing  when it should be run.

Comment: It sounds like "allergen clean" means "try to discourage growth of mold in the A/C."

Answer (score 0):

Samsung recommends to perform self-clean operation every 15 days.

Answer (score -2):

Every few weeks according the MHI Australian website:
https://mhiaa.com.au/how-air-conditioners-can-help-improve-indoor-air-quality/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/137884)